# How to split an array into intervals with given width and check count how many times, the values have appeared in each intervals C#?

Tags: c#

In my array, **arr3** has 1000 numbers in it. I have to split this array into **k** subintervals of width **differenceofMaxMin** . How can I do that? Later I have to count how many times, the values in **arr3** have matched to each interval. But I am stuck at creating intervals from array with a given width.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated!

```
          public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    double[] Statistics1 = new double[500];
    double[] Statistics2 = new double[500];
    
    double Alpha1;
    double Alpha2;

    double RV1;
    double RV2;

    Random random = new Random();
    public double RandomDoubleInclusive() //We are using this method because random.NextDouble() method gives random number 
                                          //between 0 and 1 where 0 is inclusive and 1 is exclusive. 
                                          //Since the value of probability lies between 0 and 1, both inclusive that's why we need 
                                          //to use this method.
    {
        double d = 0.0;
        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            d = random.NextDouble();
            i = random.Next(2);
        }
        while (i == 1 && d > 0);

        return d + i;

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    int i,j;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SampleSize = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

        for ( i = 0; i<500;)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 500;)
            {
                Alpha1 = RandomDoubleInclusive();
                Alpha2 = RandomDoubleInclusive();

                double LnPart = Math.Log(Alpha1);

                double part1 = (-2) * LnPart;

                double part2 = 2 * 3.14159 * Alpha2;

                double CosPart = Math.Cos(part2);

                double SinPart = Math.Sin(part2);


                RV1 = Math.Sqrt(part1) * CosPart;
                Statistics1[i] = RV1;

                RV2 = Math.Sqrt(part1) * SinPart;
                Statistics2[j] = RV2;


                i++;
                j++;
            }

        }

        var myList = new List<double>();
        myList.AddRange(Statistics1);
        myList.AddRange(Statistics2);

        double[] arr3 = myList.ToArray();

        
        double Max = arr3.Max();
        double Min = arr3.Min();

        double differenceofMaxMin = Max - Min; //calculating size of width of interval

        double k;

        k = Math.Log(SampleSize,2) + 1; //calculating number of subintervals

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the subintervals of a some standard length (in the sense of `array.length`) or are they all of the form $[a_i, a_{i+1})$ where $a_i=a_{i-1}+n$ for some constant $n$? Can’t quite tell from the text of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I can certainly try to help you out with an example on how to split an array **arr3** into **k** subintervals with (max) number of elements **differenceofMaxMin**

```
var arr3 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

// given: the max number of elements
var differenceofMaxMin = 300;
// determine the number of subintervals
// note that the last subinterval may contain less than differenceofMaxMin elements
var k = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)arr3.Count() / differenceofMaxMin);

var arr3_split = Enumerable.Range(0, k)
    .Select(i => arr3.Skip(i * differenceofMaxMin).Take(differenceofMaxMin));
```

Looking at your method to generate a random double from [0, 1], I think it's overkill since the likelihood to actually draw exactly 1.0 is extremely low.